# Python regex split but put end part of regex match back into string?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to find a regex expression that can break up paragraphs (long strings, no newline characters to worry about) into sentences with the simple rule that an of {., ?, !} followed by a whitespace and then a capital letter should be the end of the sentence (I realize this is not a good rule for real life).

I've got something partly working, but it doesn't quite do the job:

```
line = 'a b c FFF! D a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF. A'
matchObj = re.split(r'(.*?\sFFF[\.|\?|\!])\s[A-Z]', line)
print (matchObj)
```

prints

```
['', 'a b c FFF!', '', ' a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF.', '']
```

whereas I'd like to get:

```
['a b c FFF!', 'D a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF.']
```

So two questions.

- Why are there empty members (`''`) in the results?
- I understand why the `D` gets cut out from the split result - it's part of the first search. How can I structure my search differently so that the capital letter coming after the punctuation is put back so it can be included with the next sentence? In this case, how can I get D to turn up in the second element of the split result?

I know I could accomplish this with some sort of for-loop just peeling off the first result, adding back the capital letter and then doing it all over again, but this seems not-so-Pythonic. If regex is not the way to go here, is there something that still avoids the for loop?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **To solve the first problem** (empty strings in the result returned by `split()`), **use either [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.findall) or [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.finditer)**:

   ```
   >>> re.findall(r'(.*?\sFFF[\.|\?|\!])\s[A-Z]', line)
   ['a b c FFF!', ' a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF.']
   ```

   You were seeing empty strings in the output because that's what `split()` is supposed to do: split the input string using the matched groups as delimiters.
2. **For the second problem** (the missing *D* from the output), **use a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `(?=...)`**:

   ```
   >>> re.findall(r'(.*?\sFFF[\.|\?|\!])\s(?=[A-Z])', line)
   ['a b c FFF!', 'D a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF.']
   ```

   Lookaheads, negative lookaheads, lookbehinds and negative lookbehinds are four kinds of assertions that you can use to say "match this group only if followed/preceded by group, but don't consume the string".
3. Reading carefully your expression, it seems you have misunderstood the syntax of the `[...]` operator. It seems you want to match one of `.`, `?` and `!`.

   If that is the case, then you can **rewrite `[\.|\?|\!]` as `[.?!]`**:

   ```
   >>> re.findall(r'(.*?\sFFF[.?!])\s(?=[A-Z])', line)
   ['a b c FFF!', 'D a b a a FFF. gegtat FFF.']
   ```

   `[.?!]` is not only more compact, but is also more correct: with `[\.|\?|\!]` you were also matching the `|` character (so that `'a b c FFF|'` were a valid match)!